# Google Map is not opening

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

****Error:***

11-13 14:19:23.328 2629-2629/com.example.iangkur.realdemo E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iangkur.realdemo/com.example.iangkur.realdemo.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    **at com.example.iangkur.realdemo.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:41)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.iangkur.realdemo.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:41) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:465)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:50)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3736)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.iangkur.realdemo.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:41) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:443)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:50) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3736) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.iangkur.realdemo.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:41) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.<init>(Unknown Source)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

**My activity_map.xml file:**

Comment: Did you add api_key to manifest?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to make it more readable, and give a little more context to your problem

Comment: Please provide the code for `MapActivity.java` around line number 41.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        getLocationPermission();
    }

Comment: Yes, I added api_key to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in your layout xml:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Use

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

instead of

`android:name=com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`